# CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing django REST + Vuejs obtain_auth_token

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, csrf

I am making `POST` request to get the `token` from the backend. I have `traefik` to provide `https` for security reason. It works.

But when I deploy `Vuejs` and make `POST` with the same payload. I got the error in the `Chrome` browser.

```
detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing."
```

I have search over the stackoverflow. I would like to follow the security concept then disable CSRF is not an option.

```js
import {ref} from "vue";
import {BACKEND_URL} from "../constants";

const getLoginToken = () => {
  const token = ref('')
  const tokenError = ref(null)

  const fetchToken = async(username, password) => {
    try{
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "username": username,
          "password": password
        }),
        redirect: 'follow',
      }
      const url = BACKEND_URL + '/api/auth-token/'
      console.log(url)
      let data = await fetch(url, requestOptions)
      if(!data.ok){
        throw Error(data.statusText)
      }
      token.value = await data.json()
    }
    catch(err){
      tokenError.value = err.message
      console.log(tokenError.value)
    }
  }
  return { token, tokenError, fetchToken }
}

export default getLoginToken
```

`settings.py`

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",),
    "DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS": "drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema",
}
```

`urls.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
...
path("api/auth-token/", csrf_exempt(obtain_auth_token)),
...
```

But does not work.

**Problem:**
I am unable to get `token` from production server.

**Question:**
I have disable `CSRF`, but why it still error?

Answer (score 0):

Since I am in the hurry. I decided to make my own function and go.

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([])
@permission_classes([])
def my_obtain_auth_token(request, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
    """My customize obtain_auth_token."""
    serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.validated_data['user']
    token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return Response({'token': token.key})
```